# How to securely allow web apps to read/write to S3? (the new way with IAM)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I've been banging my head against a wall on this for two hours. It's frustrating that Amazon has made this so complicated when it doesn't need to be.

Let's say I have a bucket called "test," and a new IAM user "bob" with its own key ID and secret key which a web app will be using to access said bucket. How do I set this up? The Amazon docs have proven to be unhelpful.

Here's where I am so far.

I have a policy for the user to grant full access to S3:

[image]

And I have the user's key ID and secret, which I've put into Transmit just to test if I can even connect (which I can't).

I'm not sure where to go from here. I'm using the user's keys to connect and it has full access, so I don't know what's wrong. Any help would be great.

Comment: *"to test if I can even connect (which I can't)."* Okay, what does that mean?  What errors do you see?

Comment: If you're using the correct credentials and you have "AmazonS3FullAccess" as the only policy on that user then it should work. Maybe, you need to set the region somewhere in Transmit? I would suggest trying using the AWS CLI and see what error it gives you.